# Create jQuery UI Accordion Mixed Mode

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Can someone tell me how to implement mixed accordion where few of the node can be expanded or collapsed but rest of them should not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the way I implemented so that if it needed to someone can refer this.

I have used < li> tags with custom class ".custom-accordion" where I needed accordion. and skipped the other < li> where I did not wanted the accordion.

On document ready -> I have handled onclick event to hide the subsequent panel like this :

```
 $(".custom-accordion").on("click", function (e) {
    var $accordionPanel = $(this);
    $accordionPanel.toggleClass("active");
    var panel = $accordionPanel.next();
    if (panel.css('max-height') != "0px") {
        panel.css('max-height', '0px');
    } else {
        //panel.css('max-height', panel[0].scrollHeight + "px");
        panel.css('max-height', "none");

    }
    $accordionPanel.attr('aria-expanded', ($accordionPanel.attr('aria-expanded') == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false'));
});
```